# Google map inside ion-slides

Tags: css, google-maps, ionic-framework

I want to show a Map inside an ion-slide as shown in the codepen http://codepen.io/4spins/pen/dXPBGy I created, but for some reason the map isn't rendered as expected (map controls appear skewed and tiles are not shown, only grey area)

If I comment out the ion-slide part entirely and initialise the map in the `ionic.Platform.ready` (instead of the `$ionicSlides.sliderInitialized`) then everything looks normal.

Comment: Why are you using  ion-slide-page instead of ion-slide?

Comment: it's the way they are using the control in their docs http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/. An `ion-slides` slider contains multiple `ion-slide-page` elements. The `ion-slide`is supposed (if I understand correctly) to be used in the deprecated `ion-slide-box` control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this class seems to be the culprit.

```
.swiper-slide img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Add this to the CSS to simply override it.

```
#map img {
    max-height: none !important;
}
```

See if its breaking anything else.

Comment: You are correct sir. The img style is messing things up because the tiles in a Google map are Images and also the controls have a image sprite to display icons etc which is also messed up by setting the `max-height` for images in the container.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for... thanks for the solution. I'll reward the bounty once SO lets me.

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution,when i give `ion-slide` instead of `ion-slide-page`.Now the google map is working perfectly.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css">
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <!-- <script src="js/mqttws31.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sample.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ionicApp">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

**sample.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Sample" hide-nav-bar="true">
     <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Sample</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button" ng-click="showList()">List</button>
            <button class="button" ng-click="showMap()">Map</button>
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content scroll="false" class="has-header">
        <ion-slide-box delegate-handle="bottomSlide" show-pager="false">
            <ion-slide>
                <div class="box yellow">
                    <h1>List</h1></div>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <div class="box blue">
                    <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
                </div>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', [
    'ionic',
])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.options = {
        loop: false,
        speed: 500,
        onlyExternal: true,
        pagination: false
    }
    $scope.showMap = function() {
        gotoSlide(1);
    };

    $scope.showList = function() {
        gotoSlide(0);
    };
    var gotoSlide = function(index) {
        $scope.$broadcast('slideBox.setSlide', index);
    }

    function initializeMap() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493, -89.381388);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        $scope.map = map;
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);


});
```

**style**

```
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
body {
    cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
    height: 100%
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

If you need the complete source code.Please let me know.Thanks